# Possible to suppress "Cannot find or open the PDB file" warnings in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When debugging with Visual Studio 2010, sometimes there aren't PDB files available for system libraries as I've not built them myself (i.e. they've not been built for debugging). This is OK as I don't need to access them. A sample warning might be something like:

> 'Plugin Host.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\xmllite.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

However these warnings clog up the Output pane making it quite hard to debug sometimes. Is there a way to suppress these at all?

Thanks, Hemmer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These PDBs actually are available, enable the Microsoft Symbol Server support.  But yes, you can suppress these messages.  Right-click the Output window while debugging and untick "Module Load Messages".  The value is preserved for future debug sessions.  Note that it isn't actually a warning, just a diagnostic that tells you which DLLs are getting loaded.

Comment: Enabling the symbol server slows down the beginning of debugging sessions for me by ~5 seconds. Are they not cached or something?

Comment: Yes they are cached.  Slow internet connection to the Microsoft server, I'd guess.  It still tries to connect to find missing pdbs.